# Get Contact by Phone number on Android

Tags: android, cursor, android-contacts, phone-number

I know how I can get all contacts in Android , and how to get their phone number.

What I cant seem to figure out is how to get a contact by phone number...

This is my current piece of code I wrote to test which phone numbers are available:

```
// Create a cursor
    Cursor cursor = Base.contentResover().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("CALLOG", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.NUMBER)));
    }
```

The problem is that i only get a few phone numbers returned, while i expect to get all... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to accept answer(s) provided by other just clicking on check on left side of answer

Comment: Thanks man. I just adjusted all of my questions that got answers. (Only  the ones I found to have good answers)

Comment: For the facility of others, I have written a post which contains the whole code to query name, photo, contact ID, etc. with decent explanation. The code contains snippets as found on different answers, but more organized and tested. Link: http://hellafun.weebly.com/home/get-information-of-a-contact-from-number

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I dont think there is anything wrong with the snippet that you had pasted.
Try using a while loop to LOG all the phone numbers.

Regarding your requirement to fetch a contact by Phone Number.Try using the following snippet

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber)); 
resolver.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,PhoneLookup._ID...
```

Use the _ID to determine the contact.

Why to use PhoneLookup instead of Phone?

- The PhoneLookup is highly optimised
  in terms of its searches.
- Phone numbers can be entered in the
  contacts database with fillers like "(",")","-" etc PhoneLookup
  helps to decouple these fillers and  compare only the phone number.
- Comparing the values from Phone will not fetch you any result.
- It provides various other phone
  number related info.
  (HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,TIMES_CONTACTED,DISPLAY_NAME
  etc)

Hope that helps. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: `TIMES_CONTACTED` is a bad example in 2021 since it got deprecated. Maybe now after 10 years, you can update your answer lol

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to get all your contact with `name,_id and no.` You can call this method in your Activity.

```
private void displayContacts() {

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                     Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                     while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                         String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                         System.out.println("name"+name+"ph no"+phoneNo);
                         Toast.makeText(this, "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     } 
                pCur.close();
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this kind of code:

```
public void logCallLog(String number)
{
    long dialed;
    String columns[]=new String[] {
            CallLog.Calls._ID,
            CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
            CallLog.Calls.DATE,
            CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
            CallLog.Calls.TYPE};
    String args[]=new String[1];
    args[0]=number;
    Cursor c;
    c = this.managedQuery(Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"),
            columns, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER+"=?", args, "Calls._ID DESC"); //last record first
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        dialed=c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));
        if(Me.DEBUG)
            Log.v("CallLog", "Call to number: "+number+", registered at: "+new Date(dialed).toString());
    }
}
```