# How to show the name of the person instead of phone numbers?

Tags: android, menuitem

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
myIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +CallNumber));

startActivity(myIntent);
```

Is there any possibilities to show the contact name instead of the phone numbers on selecting  menuitem call?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link on stackoverflow can help:

[Get Contact by Phone number on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5555103/1287856)

First use it to retrieve the contact name based on the phone number. Then use:

```
myIntent.setData(Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/"+PersonName))
```

to call the person.