# How to get phone number from person name which are in my contact list in android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I want to get phone no of the person from his name which are in my contact list. i have used the below code but it is not working fine. Tell me where i am wrong.

```
          try {                   
        cursor_company =getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
null,ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME+ " = " + "sidharth", null, null);          
              }           
        catch(Exception e)               
        {    
        System.out.println("this is exception "+e);             
        }           
         String phone_number;           
         while (cursor_company.moveToNext()) {          
        Phone_number =cursor_company.getString(           
        cursor_company.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));             
    System.out.println(" this is user no. is"+phone_number);         
               }              
        cursor_company.close();               
         }
```

The exception came when i run this code is below

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: bhawana: , while compiling: SELECT data_version, phonetic_name, phonetic_name_style, contact_id, lookup, data12, data11, data10, mimetype, data15, data14, data13, display_name_source, data_sync1, data_sync3, data_sync2, agg_presence.chat_capability AS contact_chat_capability, data_sync4, account_type, custom_ringtone, sp, status_updates.status AS status, data1, data4, data5, data2, data3, sns_id, data8, data9, group_sourceid, data6, account_name, data7, display_name, in_visible_group, display_name_alt, contacts_status_updates.status_res_package AS contact_status_res_package, is_primary, contacts_status_updates.status_ts AS contact_status_ts, raw_contact_id, times_contacted, contacts_status_updates.status AS contact_status, status_updates.status_res_package AS status_res_package, status_updates.status_icon AS status_icon, contacts_status_updates.status_i
```

Comment: yes the exception is "column not found" i can also show u the complete one if you want

Comment: at first sight i dont see anything wrong with your code. Can you tell us what is the problem? why isn't it working fine? what is returning?

Comment: i have edited my question and give u the exception which are generated

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553867/get-contact-by-phone-number-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is it:

```
static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
};

String name_to_search = "sidharth";

String select = "(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " == \"" +name_to_search+ "\" )";
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
context.startManagingCursor(c);

if (c.moveToNext())
{
    String id = c.getString(0);
    ArrayList<String> phones = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor pCur = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
    while (pCur.moveToNext())
    {
        phones.add(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
        Log.i("", name_to_search+ " has the following phone number "+ pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
    } 
    pCur.close();   
}
```

Comment: Sure. If you find my answer useful, then please mark as answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `moveToFirst()` function of the cursor to focus on the match and then call getString