# Retrieve contact name from contact number

Tags: android, android-contacts

I referred this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553867/get-contact-by-phone-number-on-android) for fetching contact name for the provided contact number but
i wanted something which would fetch me the name even though it is saved without the country code.

For example, 
If i enter number as +918888888888 and the number is stored as 8888888888 or 08888888888, i should still be able to get the name. Can i do it using `PhoneLookup` ?

I mean i am looking for something similar to 'like' feature in database operations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if is there any straightforward approach to do that.

But you can do it like this way

```
String phoneNo = "+918888888888";       
//Search contacts for name

if(match not found)    //searching for 8888888888
{
    phoneNo = phoneNo.substring(3);
    //search again
}

if(match not found) //searching for 08888888888
{
    phoneNo = "0" + phoneNo;
    //search again
}
```

It may be quite inefficient but should work fine.